# python subprocess output issue with PIPE, when trying to capture free running outputs

Tags: c, python-3.x, subprocess, gdb

Input C Program test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with gcc
`gcc -g -o test test.c`

Run the program to see its giving the output

```
./test 
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
^C
```

Run the program using subprocess to capture output

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = "./test"
def run_command(command):
    cmds = shlex.split(cmd)
    print(cmds)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmds, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    print(outs)
    
run_command(cmd)
```

Output is empty

```
python3 test.py 
['./test']
b''
```

Replace `cmd = "./test"` with `cmd = "gdb -x load ./test"` where `load` is a file with `run` command

Output is just the gdb info, but no application output

```
python3 test.py 
['gdb', '-x', 'load', './test']
b'GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1\nCopyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\nLicense GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.\nType "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.\nThis GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".\nType "show configuration" for configuration details.\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\nFind the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.\n\nFor help, type "help".\nType "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...\nReading symbols from ./test...\n[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]\nUsing host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".\n'
```

Comment: No, it's not empty [AFAICT]. The output is being buffered up in the `stdout` stream and kernel pipe buffers. Because of the `sleep(1)` it will take a _long_ time to buffer up enough data. If you wait long enough ... Or, comment out the `sleep` line and see what happens.

Comment: Also, because the C program is an infinite loop, I think python will wait until it sees EOF on the pipe. And, it never will. And, the python script will keep allocating more memory until it runs out. For sanity [and to prevent your system from hanging], replace the `while (1)` with (e.g.) `for (int i = 1;  i <= 100;  ++i)`

Comment: @CraigEstey, Python *would* wait for EOF on the pipe if no timeout were specified in the initial `proc.communicate()` call.  But with that, Python stops waiting after 15 seconds.  When that happens, this script kills the child and then collects any remaining output, which will be finite.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a buffering issue.  When a C program's standard output is an interactive device, output to it is line-buffered by default.  Otherwise, including when the standard output is a pipe, the output to it is block-buffered.

With line-buffered output, each "Hello World!\n" is dispatched to the stream right away because of the trailing newline.  With block-buffered output, it's all saved in a buffer inside the program until that fills, then that is sent all at once.

When run via your Python script, the C program writes only about 15 short lines (195 bytes) to its block-buffered standard output, not enough to fill its buffer.  When the process is then killed via a signal, it terminates immediately without flushing the buffer, so the Python script never sees any of the output.

You can fix that by adding a `fflush(stdout);` immediately after the `printf()`.  And that's probably analogous to what `gdb` is doing.

Comment: The C program is just a sample to demonstrate the problem. In my case I am not supposed to alter any C code. I am expected to load the binaries using a shell script, which contain effectively `gdb -x load ./test` and monitor the program output for a pattern, kill/break the program, which will bring gdb console, and execute few instructions in gdb. So I need a way to monitor the free running program output through gdb, using python.

Comment: @JKJ, I cannot speak to the details of any monitored program that you do not, in fact, present.  However, it's entirely plausible that the program you want to monitor behaves similarly to the example in this regard, in which case there is nothing you can do from the Python side to get the monitored program's output any sooner.  Try running `./test | cat` from the command line.  I expect that you will get bursts of output at several-minute intervals.  This will confirm that it's about redirection of the C program's output, not about Python in particular.